# MVC / ASP.Net Best Practice for Record-Level Authorization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone have any suggestions on a good methodology for enforcing record-level authorization while maintaining separation of concerns within an ASP.Net MVC web site?

With PrincipalPermission, you can decorate a method with:

```
PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "GroupLeader")
```

to require that any visitor to that page be a member of the fixed role "GroupLeader".

Alternatively, you could decorate a method with:

```
[ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Operation = "Manage", Resource = "Group")]
```

to require that any visitor to that page be allowed generically to manage a group.

However, neither of these really address the scenario in which a user might have permission to edit some groups, but not others. As far as I can tell, even if I implement a custom `ClaimsAuthorizationManager`, there is no way to get access to the method parameters in order to do conditional authorization.

Additionally, both of the methods above just throw a `SecurityException` if the user doesn't have access rather than allowing a method to gracefully redirect the user to a page that explains what happened and what they might do to gain the necessary authorization.

Obviously, I also realize that I could just code authorization logic into the method itself and redirect accordingly, but I would rather separate that out, if possible, and keep the method code clean to only handle actually processing the request and also to be able to work within a framework that can be more generically applied.

So, is there an "out-of-the-box" way to handle this scenario, or do I have to implement a custom `IAuthorizationFilter`? I think I could handle both the record-level authorization and the graceful redirect, but without any parameters at the method level, it would be essentially a massive `if ... else if` statement.

Comment: There's nothing out of the box, but you shouldn't need a giant `if else`. In the authorization filter you have the request itself, so you can get stuff from there.

Comment: The question you are really asking is "Can I perform the operation on _this_ object?" I'm actually doing some searching related to this right now, and I haven't come across a good solution yet. Basically, you want [Discretionary Access Controls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretionary_access_control). Wikipedia describes it, but I haven't found a concrete programming pattern for this yet. "Descretionary Access Control" feels like the answer, but I need more research, because it's primarily focused on system resources (e.g. a file system or computer).

Answer (score 1):

The most straight forward way to handle this situation is creating a property on your entities to store the "owner" or "creator" of the entity. Then, when you query objects, you filter by this. For example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public string Creator { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
public ActionResult FooDetails(int id)
{
    var foo = db.Foos.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id && m.Creator == User.Identity.Name);
    if (foo == null)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    return View(foo);
}
```

It's not really appropriate to handle this via an authorization filter because you have to select the row to determine the user's permissions. Then, you must select the row again inside the action to send it to the view. Also, you'd have to do some acrobatics to get the filter to be able to know how it should select what from where so that you can even check the permissions in the first place. In the action, you're already selecting the entity, so just condition it based on whether the user "owns" it at the same time.