# Associating Data with authenticated user in ASP.NET MVC optimization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, controller, asp.net-identity

I am using ASP.NET WebAPI with the built in authentication and identity services that come with the Visual Studio template. I now have it that a user can access the system and be authenticated.

The next logical step is to allow the user to create records. Lets say the user can have a "Project". How can I associate the user with a project at the point the project is created? It seems logical that the project table will just store the `user_id` provided by User.Identity.GetUserId().

Now, say that a project consists of Tasks. By default the WebAPI will create a Tasks controller, where I post a task. I think I would need to inject some additional information (such as the project id) at the point of creating the task.

But, say someone wants to add a task a project that doesn't belong to them. I need to verify this by loading the project, and checking the `user_id` field. Now I am adding two repositories to my controller. This seems like a lot of work.

Is it my own laziness that makes this seem hard???

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a related question, as it seems like you are looking for record-level authorization.

[MVC / ASP.Net Best Practice for Record-Level Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998828/mvc-asp-net-best-practice-for-record-level-authorization)

There is merit also in using multiple repositories. See here for an example of use.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Here, you would wrap the multiple repositories up within the UnitOfWork class.

I hope this points you in the right direction.